# Error when getting song PlayPosition using Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to get the current time of a song when is playing, but when a call to `MediaPlayer.PlayPosition.TotalMilliseconds;` is made, an error is thrown:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll

Additional information: 
    HRESULT: [0xC00D9C41], 
    Module: [Unknown], 
    ApiCode: [Unknown/Unknown], 
    Message: Unknown
```

I'm learning `c#` and `monogame` and maybe I'm commiting an obvious mistake.

The code that throw that error is this:

```
public static void SpawnArcker(GameTime gametime)
{
    if (MediaPlayer.State != MediaState.Playing) return;

    elapsedtime += (float) MediaPlayer.PlayPosition.TotalMilliseconds; // <--- HERE
    //elapsedtime += (float) gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    ...
}
```

This is being called in the update method of the principal loop like this:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);

    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        Exit();
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        MediaPlayer.Play(Media.song);
    SpawnArcker(gameTime);
    ...
}
```

I though it was because I was playing large .wav files, but the same happen with short .mp3 files.

Comment: Can you explain why don't you use `elapsedtime += (float) gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;`? I think it can work quite well.

Comment: @J3soon Hi, yes it works, but I am making a rhythm based game, and I need the elapsed time in the song, if I use `gametime.ElapsedGameTime` the game get unsync with the song differently everytime the game runs so I thought getting the elapsedTime of the song would be better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if someone is interested...

After a while, I found (I guess) the meaning of this error. In [this page](http://errorco.de/win32/mferror-h/mf_e_clock_no_time_source/0xc00d9c41/) it says:

```
0xC00D9C41
#define MF_E_CLOCK_NO_TIME_SOURCE
No Presentation Time Source has been specified.
```

Then, I search for that error and found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694084(v=vs.85).aspx) where it says:

> The presentation clock does not return a valid time until the Media Session sends the MESessionTopologyStatus event with the MF_TOPOSTATUS_READY flag. **Until then, GetClock returns MF_E_CLOCK_NO_TIME_SOURCE**.

(Emphasys added)

I guess is the fact that, even when the song is "Playing", there is no time yet to get, so this error is thrown.

Too much for me, so I opt to try a different library called [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) with a similar functionality, so I reemplace everything related to `MediaPlayer` with this library and, with the same logic, now it works. This is some of the changes I made:

```
public static void SpawnArcker(WaveOutEvent waveOutDevice, Mp3FileReader audioFileReader)
{
    if (waveOutDevice.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Playing) return;

    elapsedtime += (float) audioFileReader.CurrentTime.TotalMilliseconds - aux_elapsedtime;
    aux_elapsedtime = (float) audioFileReader.CurrentTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    //... rest of code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had the same error using `GetClock` and `GetCorrelatedTime` with a media session in C++

Comment: After struggling some more I discovered that there seems to be an error in the docs: when I wait on `MF_TOPOSTATUS_READY` I still get the same error, while when I wait on `MF_TOPOSTATUS_STARTED_SOURCE` I do not (finally...), which makes sense to me: you cannot request play time when the song hasn't started playing. I hope that this is useful to someone!

Comment: (Alternatively, it seems you can wait for `MESessionStarted`)